# Use raspberry pi as gateway

Tags: raspbian, networking

I want to use my unit as a gateway so I can share its openvpn enabled connection with the rest of my LAN like this guide states: 
http://rodrigo.sharpcube.com/2010/06/20/using-and-sharing-a-vpn-connection-on-your-mac/

But can't find a replacement for ipfw on raspbian :S

(What I want to achieve is just having to change the default gateway on my smart TV and other devices and connect through my raspberry)

Comment: How is your network topology? Is everything connected to the inside of the same router or is the RPi an interconnecting link?

Comment: All connected to the same router

Answer (score 1):

The linux counterpart to ipfw for mac is [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables), which you should be using instead.

The openvpn wiki has a page on bridging and routing using iptables: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting